# Lint Warning: Variable is already assigned to this value

Tags: android, android-studio, warnings, lint

I get the lint warning
`Variable is already assigned to this value`
when doing something like the following

```
String[] sa =getStringArray();
sa = modifyArrayandMakeAwesomer(sa);  //get the warning here
```

Seems to be a new warning for me.  Perhaps my lint settings have changed.  The code works as expected without any errors.  Is it bad practice?  Should I declare a second string array?

Answer (score 9):

Because `modifyArrayandMakeAwesomer(sa)` is modifying your data using its reference,

```
class Person {
   String name;
}

// this method just return the string value after making it uppercase,
public static Person modifyReference(Person p)
{
  p.name = "Gaurav";
  return p; // we don't need to return this from here since we are modifying directly to the reference.
}

public static int main(String[] args)
{
  Person p = new Person();
  p.name = "Max";
  System.out.println(p.name);
  modifyReference(p); // this is what you should do,
  p = modifyReference(p); // this is useless, since you have passed the reference of Person class 
  System.out.println(p.name);
}
```

Comment: But isn't Java a pass-by-value language? How is this consistent with the rest of the semantics?

Comment: @GovindMohan Java is pass by value. BUT, the variable that is passed is a reference since it is not a primitive.

Answer (score -6):

Well Your code is potentially confusing. That's why you are Getting this warning.

You could disable "Variable is assigned to itself" inspection in "File | Settings | Editor | Inspections | Java - Declaration redundancy".

Comment: This makes no sense!

Comment: This suggestion hides the actual problem instead of solving it.